# Eclipse 3.6 create temlate code for enclosing project

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, eclipse-plugin

I use Eclipse 3.6 for developing OpenEdge. For specific reasons i need templates variables which are not specified. I have ${time},${date}, etc, but I need others. So i decompiled the template classes and developed into them (org.eclipse.text_3.5.0.v20100601-1300.zip\org\eclipse\jface\text\templates\GlobalTemplateVariables.class).

I need the current project name to be inserted in a template(in JAVA).

[image: Projects image]

I've currently soluved that by getting all the running tasks, and from the titles I get the exact string (tasklist.exe /fo csv /nh). It's not the best, but it works.
The problem is, that on Windows 10 this command is super slow, so i have to figure out another way to get the current project name from the template code.

I tried this:

```
IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
...
...
...
```

But it crashed, and i cannot debug it.

Is there another way to get the current project from a template code in Eclipse 3.6?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I tried handling any exceptions by this method:

```
        PrintWriter writer;
        try {
            writer = new PrintWriter("c:\\Progress\\ProjectResources\\aaaa" +  ".txt", "UTF-8");
            writer.println("I've come this far");
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        try {

            IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
            IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
            IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();
            IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
            return "faja";
        } catch (Exception e){

            try {
                writer = new PrintWriter("c:\\Progress\\ProjectResources\\aaaa" +  ".txt", "UTF-8");
                writer.println(e.getMessage());
                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex2.printStackTrace();
            }   

        }
```

I've got the first "message" written in the file (aaaa.txt --> "I've come this far") but not the second (e.getMessage()). Nothing in the logs, nothing on the screen, nothing in the file i just created.

Comment: What does 'crashed' mean? What happens exactly.

Comment: The code stops at the first line (IWorkbench...) and none of the other code runs

Comment: 'The code stops' - how? Do you get exception (which)? Check the .log file in the workspace .metadata for logged errors.

Comment: I don't get any exceptios :( i updated with the exception handling, please check